# Definite Clause Grammar - Prolog

Tags: parsing, prolog, dcg

Below I have a Definite Clause Grammar that should accept the string `aabccc`, however when I tested the grammar, the only string I was able to get accepted was `abc`.

I'm pretty sure I've gotten rid of left-hand recursion, so I'm not sure what's going wrong.

```
s --> x, y, z.
x --> [a], x.
x --> [a].
y --> [b], y.
y --> [b]. 
z --> [c], z.
z --> [c].
```

Also, would I be able to define the above grammar as...

```
s --> x, y, z.
x --> [a], x; [a].
y --> [b], y; [b].
z --> [c], z; [c].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both version of your grammar work as expected:

```
?- phrase(s, [a,a,b,b,c,c,c], R).
R = [] .

?- phrase(s, [a,a,b,b,c,c,c]).
true .
```

Maybe the issue was that you're trying to call it not with e.g. a `[a,a,b,b,c,c,c]` list of tokens but with a `aabccc` atom? If that's the case, you can use the standard `atom_chars/2` built-in predicate to convert an atom into a list of characters:

```
?- atom_chars(aabccc, Tokens).
Tokens = [a, a, b, c, c, c].
```

Comment: The above grammar works. I just needed to re-compile it. Thank you :)